# Vertically separate arraylist to sublists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which contains String arrays.
I need to separate this arraylist to sub ArrayLists like separating columns,

like

Arraylist columns to

ArrayList columnOne, ArrayList columnTwo....

No, I need to separate ArrayList to ArrayList like

```
ArrayList<String[]> data=

["cold","yes"]
["cold","no"]
["hot","no"]


ArrayList<String>

ArrayList<String> columnOne= ["cold","cold","hot"]
ArrayList<String> columnTwo= ["yes","no","no"]
```

It looks like easy with using loop but may be there is more simple way on initialize ArrayList?

Comment: Use: `Arrays.asList(String[])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need if I understood well your requirements.
Please adjust the code to test if columnIndex is a valid column index.
You have also to decide what is necessary to do if not all arrays have the same dimension.

```
public List<String> getColumnList(List<String[]> strArrayList, int columnIndex) {
    List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < strArrayList.size(); i++) {
        columnList.add(strArrayList.get(i)[columnIndex]);
    }
    return columnList;
}
```